# Convergence of subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $B$ be a subset of a metric space $X$.

Let $(z_n)$ be any sequence in $\bar B$.

Then, I know, there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $B$ such that;

$d(x_n, z_n) \leq \frac1n\space\forall n$.

Now, if it is given that $(x_n)$ has a subsequence that converges in $\bar B$, then how can I show that $(z_n)$ has a subsequence that converges in $\bar B$?

Answer (score 1):

Well if there exists $y\in \overline{B}$ such that $x_n\to y$, then the triangle inequality gives you that:

$$ d(z_n,y)\leq d(z_n,x_n)+d(x_n,y), $$

and since both these terms tend to $0$, $d(z_n,y)$ also tends to $0$.

Or am I missing something?